# jQuery - refresh or trigger all events for same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I've this element

```
<img class="imgclass" src="img.jpg">
```

And this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.imgclass').click(function(){
    alert('Works!!!');
    }); //click
// I need to load something in other moment
$(something).load(function(){
    $('<img src="iamge.jpg">').addClass('imgclass').insertAfter('img');
    });
});
```

If I click first IMG, it works, but second, nothing. How colud i refresh classes event without copying all the function?

The example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q860upLv/2/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read this... about delegation.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

---

Change this:

```
$('.imgclass').click(function(){
```

To this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".imgclass", function(){
```

[Your example.](https://jsfiddle.net/q860upLv/3/)